# Adding YEAR TO MONTH interval to TIMESTAMP value

Tags: sql, oracle, date, plsql

I have a case where I have add `YEAR TO MONTH` interval to a `TIMESTAMP` value & to achieve this I am using it this way

```
SELECT (END_DATE + NUMTOYMINTERVAL(2, 'MONTH')) FROM DUAL
```

Above code works successfully for almost all END_DATE values except for certain values.

For Example, when `END_DATE = 31-JULY-2013`, Expected result for above code is `30-SEPT-2013` but it throws an error

```
ORA-01839: date not valid for month specified
```

This is because the above code returns `31-SEPT-2013` which is an invalid date.

Is there any alternate way to achieve this?

(I can use `ADD_MONTHS` but issue with this function it returns only `DATE` values & I need `TIMESTAMP` as return value)

Am i missing anything?

Comment: :Does you end date contains timestamp?

Comment: Does `end_date` have fractional seconds? Do you always want to adjust the date if it's the month-end; so would 2 months after 2013-02-28 be 2013-04-28, or 2013-04-30? Indeed, is it always the last day of a month?

Comment: @GauravSoni Yes,END_DATE is timestamp value.

Answer (score 3):

Since `end_date` does not have fractional seconds, or indeed any time component, you can use `add_months` and cast it to a `timestamp`:

```
select cast(add_months(end_date, 2) as timestamp) from ...
```

But `add_months` has its own quirks. If the original date is the last day of the month, you'll get the last day of the adjusted month - which is what you want if you're going to a shorter month in this case, but maybe not if you're going the other way:

```
with t as (
select to_timestamp('2013-07-31', 'YYYY-MM-DD') as end_date from dual
union all select to_timestamp('2013-06-30', 'YYYY-MM-DD') from dual
union all select to_timestamp('2013-02-28', 'YYYY-MM-DD') from dual
union all select to_timestamp('2012-02-29', 'YYYY-MM-DD') from dual
)
select end_date, cast(add_months(end_date, 2) as timestamp)
from t;

END_DATE                       CAST(ADD_MONTHS(END_DATE,2)AST
------------------------------ ------------------------------
2013-07-31 00:00:00.000000     2013-09-30 00:00:00.000000
2013-06-30 00:00:00.000000     2013-08-31 00:00:00.000000
2013-02-28 00:00:00.000000     2013-04-30 00:00:00.000000
2012-02-29 00:00:00.000000     2012-04-30 00:00:00.000000
```

Or you could create your own function to handle the bad dates, and adjust backwards until it finds a valid one:

```
create or replace function adjust_timestamp(orig_ts in timestamp,
  months in number)
return timestamp is
  new_ts timestamp;
  offset number := 0;
  bad_adjustment exception;
  pragma exception_init(bad_adjustment, -01839);
begin
  while new_ts is null loop
    begin
      new_ts := orig_ts - numtodsinterval(offset, 'DAY')
        + numtoyminterval(months, 'MONTH');
    exception
      when bad_adjustment then
        offset := offset + 1;
        continue;
    end;
  end loop;
  return new_ts;
end;
/
```

This uses an exception defined for the ORA-01839 error code to trap a bad date, and it does it in a loop so it can work backwards (via the `offset`) until it finds one that doesn't error.

```
with t as (
select to_timestamp('2013-07-31', 'YYYY-MM-DD') as end_date from dual
union all select to_timestamp('2013-06-30', 'YYYY-MM-DD') from dual
union all select to_timestamp('2013-02-28', 'YYYY-MM-DD') from dual
union all select to_timestamp('2012-02-29', 'YYYY-MM-DD') from dual
)
select end_date, adjust_timestamp(end_date, 2)
from t;

END_DATE                       ADJUST_TIMESTAMP(END_DATE,2)
------------------------------ ------------------------------
2013-07-31 00:00:00.000000     2013-09-30 00:00:00.000000
2013-06-30 00:00:00.000000     2013-08-30 00:00:00.000000
2013-02-28 00:00:00.000000     2013-04-28 00:00:00.000000
2012-02-29 00:00:00.000000     2012-04-29 00:00:00.000000
```

Which gives different results to the `add_months` version. You need to be sure what you're getting, and how you want the data to behave.

Answer (score 2):

This is expected behavior as specified by ANSI - see [this AskTom](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:68920891856765).  If you add two months to 30-JUL-2013 you'll get 30-SEP-2013, which I think is perfectly understandable.  If you add two months to 31-JUL-2013 you'll get...what?  There is no 31-SEP-2013 - only 30 days in September.  So, what's the system supposed to do?  Should it give you 30-SEP-2013?  Should it give you 01-OCT-2013?  Neither of these is correct.  You've asked it two change the month value forward by two months.  OK, it tries that and finds that the resultant date is not valid - so it throws an error.

Oh, dear.

BUT - thankfully, we are not mere mortals.  We are superior beings.  We are software developers.  We have MANUALS!!!!  WE ARE NIGH UNTO GODS!!!!!!!!!!

So, consulting [the manual](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions004.htm#i76717) we find we have the ADD_MONTHS function available to us, which does pretty much what you're looking for here.  However, ADD_MONTHS only operates on DATE values, so your fractional seconds would be lost IF you didn't do some extra playing around to save them.  But, as I said, we are software developers...

Example:

```
DECLARE 
  tsIn  TIMESTAMP := TO_TIMESTAMP('31-JUL-2013 17:31:01', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS');
  tsOut TIMESTAMP;
  nFrac_secs  NUMBER;
  strBuffer   VARCHAR2(1000);
  strFrac_secs VARCHAR2(1000);
BEGIN
  tsIn := tsIn + NUMTODSINTERVAL(0.1234, 'SECOND');

  strBuffer := TO_CHAR(tsIn);
  strFrac_secs := SUBSTR(strBuffer, -10, 7);

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('tsIn=' || tsIn);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('strBuffer=' || strBuffer);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('strFrac_secs=' || strFrac_secs);

  nFrac_secs := TO_NUMBER(strFrac_secs);

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('nFrac_secs=' || nFrac_secs);

  tsOut := ADD_MONTHS(tsIn, 2);

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('tsOut before restoring fractional seconds=' || tsOut);

  tsOut := tsOut + NUMTODSINTERVAL(nFrac_secs, 'SECOND');

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('tsOut after restoring fractional seconds=' || tsOut);
END;
```

So, basically, if you try doing interval arithmetic Oracle follows the *&^#@$#* ANSI spec and plays stupid.  They then give you a function (which is, to be fair, documented) which does more-or-less what's wanted, BUT only does it on DATE values.    I think this is what's called "job security"...

:-)

Share and enjoy.

Comment: +1, although the OP mentioned `add_months`, and comments established fractional seconds aren't an issue here (but not why it's a timestamp at all in that case). This will be useful to someone though. The `add_month` behaviour isn't always as expected/wanted either. The first step is establishing the required output for the edge cases.

Comment: @AlexPoole - thanks.  I went through all the junk required to use ADD_MONTHS because of the OP's mention that it dropped the fractional seconds.  (I'd orginally started on a solution much like yours but changed horses midstream).  This is admittedly a kluge, but if we are to be nigh unto gods we must be willing to grab (using gloves, of course) the gonads of the universe and squeeze - or what's a heaven for?  :-)

Comment: Well, there's an image... thanks! I thought the OP's comment - now deleted - was that there were no fractional seconds and it's just a date entered by a user, not that they existed and were dropped. Maybe I misunderstood. Just for a change.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `add_months` to go to the correct date, then add the fractional part of the timestamp:

```
SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
       CAST(CAST(add_months(trunc(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), 2) AS TIMESTAMP) +
            (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP -
             CAST(trunc(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) as timestamp)) as timestamp)
FROM DUAL;
```

Note that you'll lose the timezone.